# Is there an equivalent to Smalltalk’s #copyWithout: in Cocoa’s collection classes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsset

In Smalltalk i am used to make a copy of a collection without an undesired element like this:

```
myCollection copyWithout: undesiredObject
```

which answers a copy of the receiver that does not contain any elements equal to `undesiredObject`.

Is there an equivalent in Cocoa?
If not, what is the best way to achieve such a copy?
I am especially interested in copying instances of `NSSet`.

Comment: I don't know Smalltalk but if you take a look at the `minusSet:` method of `NSMutableSet` it might give you ideas for how to match the behaviour.

Comment: It does not look like there is a built-in method for doing it (although there is a method for making a copy that has an extra object added to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent in the Cocoa Foundation classes.

Possible method #1:

```
NSSet *withoutUndesiredObject = [myCollection objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    return ![obj isEqualTo:undesiredObject];
}];
```

Possible method #2:

```
NSMutableSet *withoutUndesiredObject = [myCollection mutableCopy];
[withoutUndesiredObject removeObject:undesiredObject];
```

Similar methods exist also for the other collection classes `NSArray`
and `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Thank you, I added #copyWithout as a category to NSSet using your implementation #1, as this gives back a NSSet and not a NSMutableSet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at NSIndexSet, which will give you a lot more flexibility.